# Can't install kurento-media-server on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: kurento

I followed the kurento installation from http://doc-kurento.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation_guide.html, but when I ran the command:

```
sudo apt-get install kurento-media-server-6.0
```

I get the following error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 kurento-media-server-6.0 : Depends: kms-core-6.0 (>= 6.6.1) but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: libglibmm-2.4-1c2a (>= 2.36.2) but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: libsigc++-2.0-0c2a (>= 2.0.2) but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: gstreamer1.5-plugins-bad (>= 1.7.0~0) but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: gstreamer1.5-plugins-good (>= 1.7.0~0) but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: kms-elements-6.0 (>= 6.6.1) but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: kms-filters-6.0 (>= 6.6.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Answer (score 1):

The instructions are for Ubuntu 14.04LTS, follow below steps, using these steps I installed it in Ubuntu 16.04

```
echo "deb http://ubuntu.kurento.org xenial kms6" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kurento.list
wget -O - http://ubuntu.kurento.org/kurento.gpg.key | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install kurento-media-server-6.0
```